# android:gravity="center" is not working in Pre-Lollipop OS?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I have made an Android Application and I know that Pre-Lollipop devices are negligible as compared to post-lollipop devices.

I recently ran my app on Emulator and found out that the text is not aligned to center when the gravity = "center". You can see the Image attached[image]

The Text Sync and the icon is not at the center but on post lollipop devices they are at the center. The xml code for the above case is :

```
  <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/contacts"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:text="CONTACTS"
                        android:textColor="#444444"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/line1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/barlayout"
                        android:background="@color/colorDivider2" />


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sync_layout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contacts"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contacts"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/sync_contacts"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ripplebg_viewscircle"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:rotation="0"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kj_sync" />


                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/sync_progress_bar"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/sync_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sync_layout"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sync_layout"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sync_layout"
                        android:text="Sync"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#4A4A4A"
                        />
```

Can you tell me why this is happening and the remedy for this?

Comment: Your textview has width and height `wrap_content`, so what is the need for gravity?

Comment: But i set the align_top and align_bottom to the other layout. I think i need to set the gravity? How am i going to  align it center to the layout?

Comment: Can you post full xml?

Comment: Updated! Also what is happening to the icon which is at extreme right. I have set the center_vertical attribute to true as you can see in the code. And it is not working too.

Comment: This is not the full xml. What is the parent container?

Comment: Full xml is too long and it is out of scope to the question i have posted the xml for the "Contacts" text and the two items which are at extreme right.

Comment: The image you posted has nothing to do with the xml. When a view has has width and height `wrap_content` can never appear like the image, because there is no space for the contents of the view to be centered. The boundaries of the view wrap the contents.

Comment: I have set the image center_vertical to the parent layout, i think thats possible and xml could look like that. I know i have hardcoded the ht and wdth but it is inside the relative layout and i can set the center_Vertical property and it is working fine in post lollipop. Any suggestions?

Comment: The parent layout of the image has also width and height wrap_content and since the imageview is the only visible view inside it then center_vertical does nothing.

Comment: But i have aligned the top and bottom to another view. Do you think match parent would work?

Comment: No I don't think anything because as I said earlier the image you posted has nothing to do with the xml. `android:gravity="center"` has no effect to a view with width and height `wrap_content`

Comment: But sir, why the results are different from pre and post lollipop devices? My question was that only.

Comment: I can't say, because from the clues that you give me I can't reproduce it.

Comment: you need to set the layout gravity if your parent layout in Relative then using centervertical= true etc